# Connection timeout in SMTP mailgun

Tags: php, smtp, mailgun

Getting the following error while creating connection in SMTP Mailgun

```
2017-07-30 06:46:46 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mailgun.org:2195, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2017-07-30 06:51:00 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.mailgun.org:2195 (Connection timed out) [/var/www/html/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php line 294] 
2017-07-30 06:51:00 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
2017-07-30 06:51:00 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Any help will be appreciating. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be a configuration issue? Check your settings on mailgun side, if you are sure is not on PHPMailer

Comment: i have checked all Configuration in PHP Mailer side.

Comment: Is the port number 2195 correct? Their [website](http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/) does not list it...

Comment: i am using port number : 587

Comment: But your post specifies port 2195 here: `ssl://smtp.mailgun.org:2195` - Are you providing that url?

Comment: @Rajnish Did you find a solution here?

Comment: Are you getting a timeout all the time, or just sometimes? Please share some code, secret keys redacted. What timeout do you have configured?